# Scheduled class not showing up in scheduled jobs

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I am trying to run an apex class daily using System.schedule but It is not showing up in scheduled jobs nor I am able to query from Cron trigger on owner Id as my Id
This is the piece of code.
Note : - I need to run my apex class everyday

```
global class scheduledDeactivation implements Schedulable {
    public static String sch = '0 0 12 1/1 12 ? 2022'; 
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      deactivateUsers usrs = new deactivateUsers();
      String jobID = System.schedule('Deactivate Inactive Users', sch, usrs);
      System.debug(jobId);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the entire class

Comment: Do you need apex class as well?

Comment: You seem to have a big misunderstanding about how scheduled jobs work. You don't schedule from *within* the `execute` method. That's what's supposed to happen once you hit the scheduled time and actually want to run your logic. You *execute* the job, or carry out the functionality you intend to run at the ordained time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Common Misconception**

When you write jobs which implement `Batchable` or `Schedulable`, stick with the `public` modifier. You should *never* use the `global` modifier unless you actually need it (`webservice` functionality or `ApexRest`) or if you are building a tool which you intend to distribute through a managed package but still want the code to be visible to others.

---

You don't schedule your job from within the `execute` method! You should schedule the job from somewhere outside the job. Otherwise every time it runs you add a duplicate job to the queue. The two most common ways to schedule a job which implements the `Schedulable` interface are:

1. **Through the UI.**

   - If you have a simple schedule like every day at X hour, use the UI to schedule.
   - Navigate to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Apex Classes`.
   - Click the <kbd>Schedule Apex</kbd> button and select your class/schedule.
   - Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
2. **Through a script.**

   - If you have a more complicated schedule, you *can* schedule the job using the `system.schedule` method.
   - Open up the `Developer Console` (or your IDE of choice) and go to `Execute Anonymous`.
   - Fire off a script that calls `system.schedule` similar to what you are currently attempting in your `execute` method.